# Merging lines in a view into a new view

Tags: merge, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a view with 7 columns. 4 columns contain the same information, two of three other columns contain NULL when one column (out of these three) contain something (NOT NULL). The columns "Gewicht, aantal, klant" have to be merged into one line with the four first columns containing the information that is the same in all three lines.
How can i create a view with these lines merged into 1 line?

now view looks like:

```
> 
Produtielijn                    Datum_tijd              Artikel     PRorder             Gewicht  aantal       klant
Afzaklijn 3 (Groot Loosbroek)   2017-01-16 15:55:04.000 0118903G34  PR0800055654.006    NULL    NULL          30041 NE06-07 Garretsen
Afzaklijn 3 (Groot Loosbroek)   2017-01-16 15:55:04.000 0118903G34  PR0800055654.006    NULL    205           NULL
Afzaklijn 7 (BB Veghel)         2017-01-02 16:40:32.000 0125995AA11 PR0800055388        NULL    NULL          31488 NE49-69 Mohle(Jarco)
Afzaklijn 7 (BB Veghel)         2017-01-02 16:40:32.000 0125995AA11 PR0800055388        2600    NULL          NULL
Afzaklijn 7 (BB Veghel)         2017-01-02 16:40:32.000 0125995AA11 PR0800055388        NULL    4             NULL
```

I want the view to look like:

```
    Produtielijn                    Datum_tijd              Artikel     PRorder             Gewicht  aantal       klant
Afzaklijn 3 (Groot Loosbroek)   2017-01-16 15:55:04.000 0118903G34  PR0800055654.006        NULL       205        30041 NE06-07 Garretsen
Afzaklijn 7 (BB Veghel)         2017-01-02 16:40:32.000 0125995AA11 PR0800055388            2600       4          31488 NE49-69 Mohle(Jarco)
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost you want to sort your data out.

Secondly, assuming you have one row per value in each of your `Gewicht`, `aantal` and `klant` columns with the 'non-values' *always* being `NULL` you can just use `max` and `group by`:

```
select Produtielijn
      ,Datum_tijd
      ,Artikel
      ,PRorder
      ,max(Gewicht) as Gewicht
      ,max(aantal) as aantal
      ,max(klant) as klant
from View
group by Produtielijn
        ,Datum_tijd
        ,Artikel
        ,PRorder
```

Comment: Very simple actually. Thx